# Javascript: what lookup is faster: array.indexOf vs object hash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have to perform a *LOT* of lookups, while parsing xmlStream if i need some tag or not.

I can do it with array.indexOf method (i have about ~15 items in array) or using object[key] lookup.

Second solution seems more efficient in theory for me, but does not look line nice in my code. But if it is really more efficient, i would leave it as it is.

E.g.:

```
var tags = [
    'tag1',
    'tag2',
    'tag3',
    ...
];

var tags2 = {
    'tag1' : null,
    'tag2' : null,
    'tag3' : null,
}

tags.indexOf(value) // exists?
tags2[value] // exists?
```

Comment: indexOf is O(n), hash is O(1), afaik

Comment: Have you tried it? http://jsperf.com/

Comment: https://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-hash

Comment: It seems a good question to me, why was it downvoted?

Comment: I'd say chose the structure that makes the most sense. 15 items is nothing, it won't be noticeable, you risk making the code hard to read for no apparent benefit.

Comment: in understandable language lookup in hash takes constant time and indexOf is linear time.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/array-indexof-vs-object-hash-lookup

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, the performance depends on your set size and your access pattern. In general, the indexOf is O(n) and hash is O(1), however, since you only have about 15 items in the set and let's say each access is completely independent and equiprobable, the advantage of hash isn't really there.

Answer (score 62):

`Object` key lookup is faster than `Array.indexOf()`. You can check it on [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/array-indexof-vs-object-key-lookup2/12).

Test Results:

## Array

Index of 10000 items: 26,547 Operations/sec

Index of 100000 items: 2,493 Operations/sec

## Object

Lookup key of 10000 items: 152,115 Operations/sec

Lookup key of 100000 items: 150,450 Operations/sec

Comment: That is significant. Thank you for linking to the test