# Looking for matches in different arrays (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script in Google Apps Script:

```
 for(var i=0; i<lastCode; i++) {
  var productCode = prodCodesArr[i];
    for(var j=0; j<kelliLastCode; j++) {
     var kelliProductCode = kelliCodesArr[j];
     if(productCode == kelliProductCode) {

     Logger.log('match found')
     }
     }        
  }
```

The 2 arrays are created dynamically. So the idea is (and I know there must be MUCH better ways to do this, but I am pretty new to this so bear with me) that I am setting i to the value of the first product code in one array and then looping through the other array whilst storing the product codes in this one to j. Now, I tried logging:

```
Logger.log(productCode + ' - ' + kelliProductCode);
```

And this worked and indeed, there were instances where productCode and kelliProduct code matched.

Yet my if statement above does not pick these up.

Again, I'm sure I've botched this entirely but any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: What type is the productCode and kelliProductCode? Are they Strings, Integers or something else?

Comment: Does using `===` instead of `==` help?

Comment: they are strings. And sadly no I tried that :(

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried doing `.trim()` on the Strings? This should get rid of any whitespace.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the 2 arrays. Also, `lastCode = prodCodesArr.length` and `kelliLastCode = kelliCodesArr.length` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the point of the check? To determine which of your `prodCodesArr` items are also in `kelliCodesArr`? Why not parse `kelliCodesArr` just once, and then use hash lookups instead of array traversal? This will mean that you don't have to use nested `for` loops, which will scale very poorly as the inner loop size grows. An example (with some checks for assumptions on my part):

```
function foo() {
  const kelliCodes = getKelliCodesArraySomehow();
  const productCodes = getProductCodesArraySomehow();

  // If these are 2D arrays, note that for `var a = ['help']; var b = ['help'];`
  // `a` is never equal to `b` because they are not the exact same object in memory.
  if (kelliCodes.length && Array.isArray(kelliCodes[0])) {
    throw new TypeError("This SO answer was predicated on `kelliCodes` and `productCodes` being 1D arrays, but they aren't!");
  }

  const kelliLookup = kelliCodes.reduce(function (obj, kpc, idx) {
    if (typeof kpc === 'object') {
      console.log({message: "This SO answer assumed kpc was a string", kpc: kpc});
      throw new TypeError("You probably want to store a property of this object, not the whole object");
    }
    obj[kpc] = idx;
    return obj;
  }, {});

  var productsAlsoInKelliCodes = productCodes.filter(function (pc) {
    return kelliLookup.hasOwnProperty(pc);
  });
  productsAlsoInKelliCodes.forEach(function (pc) {
    Logger.log("The index of this product code %s in kelliCodes is %s", pc, kelliLookup[pc]);
  });
}
```

If your ___codes arrays are 2D arrays, you should flatten them before comparison, as comparing an `Array` instance to another `Array` instance will always return false, even if they contain the same element primitives--they aren't the exact same `Array` instance:

References

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness
- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [In JS, which is faster: Object's "in" operator or Array's indexof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737850/in-js-which-is-faster-objects-in-operator-or-arrays-indexof)
- [Javascript: what lookup is faster: array.indexOf vs object hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234733/javascript-what-lookup-is-faster-array-indexof-vs-object-hash)

I'm sure there are more.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help you to see what's happening:

```
function compareA(prodCodesArr,kelliCodesArr) {
  var html="";
  for(var i=0;i<prodCodesArr.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<kelliCodesArr.length;j++) {
      if(productCodesArr[i]==kelliCodesArr[j]) {
        html+=Utilities.formatString('Matched: %s=%s', productCodesArr[i],kelliCodesArr[j]);
      }else{
        html+=Utilities.formatString('No-Match: %s=%s', productCodesArr[i],kelliCodesArr[j]);
      }                             
    }        
  }
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Comparing')
}
```